# diff: text file permission denied

Tags: bash, unix, text-files, diff

I am on Windows and using diff to compare two text files. It was working successfully for small files but, when I start comparing 2GB file with another 2GB file it shows me:

```
diff: C:/inetpub/wwwroot/webclient/database_sequences/est_mouse_2.txt: Permission denied
```

My code:

```
$OldDatabaseFile = "est_mouse_1";
$NewDatabaseFile = "est_mouse_2";
shell_exec("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe --login -c 'diff $text_files_path/$OldDatabaseFile.txt $text_files_path/$NewDatabaseFile.txt >  $text_files_path/TempDiff_$OldDatabaseFile$NewDatabaseFile.txt 2>&1'");
```

`est_mouse_1.txt` and `est_mouse_2.txt` are created by me and I check file permission and folder permission, it is full control. And all other text files which I compared are in the same folder and they were successfully compared.

Any idea?

Comment: What file system are you using? Note that there are severe limitations for files with a size above 2GB an MS-Windows systems.

Comment: @arkascha How can I know it? I am using windows 7 64bit

Comment: WIn32 or Win64? Do you launch you code "as Administrator"?

Comment: @Eugene win 64bit. yes admin

Comment: The file system type should be shown somewhere amongst the meta information about the device. I think that is called "properties" in MS-Windows.

Comment: @arkascha it is NTFS

Comment: @Eugene it is NTFS

Comment: OK, if I recall correctly then that file system supports big files. Since the original `diff` utility works sequentially that cannot be the issue as well. That leaves the file operation, the shell invoked and the process environment. You appear to be using something like `bash` in an MS-Windows system, which is kind of exotic. It might well be that there are limitations and it is unclear what that `diff` utility actually is you invoke. So I would not dare to point into a specific direction here.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks dear. Hope someone else can help me

Answer (score 1):

You are using cygwin for this operation, Cygwin's heap is extensible. However, it does start out at a fixed size and attempts to extend it may run into memory which has been previously allocated by Windows.
Heap memory can be allocated up to the size of the biggest available free block in the processes virtual memory (VM). On 64 bit systems this results in a 4GB VM for a process started from that executable. I think that why you can't compare two 2GB files, I agree that the error pretty strange but explains that your access to the memory is limited. Please see [cygwin user guide](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/cygwin-ug-net.html) for the more info.

Comment: It was working for small text files. This issue appears when I compare huge text files. My RAM is 4 GB. Do you think the problem will be solved if I change my RAM? I think it is not related but, why it appears in case of huge files?

Comment: No, I think this is cygwin problem. Why it so important to you to use cygwin? You just reach the cygwin maximum that why it works with small files.

Comment: I use it in my graduation project. one of my project processes is to compare 2 text files and find the differences which diff do.

Comment: @Can I write the output of fc in a new file?

Comment: @sara You always may to redirect the output to the file. [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/206123/how-to-use-fc-file-compare-from-the-windows-command-prompt/) more info about the tool

Comment: after test fc, its main job is finds the (similarity) between files. Once it see that there is a lot of mismatches, it stoped. I want some tool that do what diff does which list the differences.